# What does this warning error mean ? UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning - Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, exception, promise

> (node:1616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:1616) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The text of the warning seems to be pretty clear. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Actually I trying to fix it but since I'm new in nodeJs world I don't know how to do so. May I help sir ? please !!

Comment: @Singou We can't help you without the code that causes this message and the full error